# Fetch/extract the .extension from a file path

Tags: ruby, string

I need to extract the `.` extension from the following paths:

1. `(_OasvkDSOEee_ruCXphIMsQ) /com.c.rb.gold.gbl.fw.proxy.component_jar/src/main/java/com/roup/ebus/mobile/api/common/resource/APIProxyResource.java`
2. `(_7ZgAUO-qEeeFqO9kl3sUYw) /cbmo-thgcb-ext-gm.war/src/main/app/WEB-INF/classes/rules/THMBK/APIRequestResponseMapper.xml`
3. `(_TM6vEFKjEee-NMziq4x8wA) /com.citi.rb.gold.memfis.sb.war/src/main/webapp/citibank/eclipselite/bank/memfis/sb/maintenance/SBBondCalculatorPopup.jsp`

Every filepath above starts with "n" number of white-spaces. I need only the `.` and the part that follows it, such as:

- `.java`
- `.xml`
- `.jsp`
- `.anything`

Please help on it.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far and what result you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`File.extname`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-extname):

```
File.extname("/abcd/INF/classes/rules/THMBK/APIRequestResponseMapper.xml")
=> .xml
File.extname("fdsfdsdf /abcd/INF/classes/rules/THMBK/APIRequestResponseMapper.xml")
=> ".xml"
```

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the strings in an array like so:

```
strings = [
  "(_OasvkDSOEee_ruCXphIMsQ) /com.c.rb.gold.gbl.fw.proxy.component_jar/src/main/java/com/roup/ebus/mobile/api/common/resource/APIProxyResource.java",
  "(_7ZgAUO-qEeeFqO9kl3sUYw) /cbmo-thgcb-ext-gm.war/src/main/app/WEB-INF/classes/rules/THMBK/APIRequestResponseMapper.xml",
  "(_TM6vEFKjEee-NMziq4x8wA) /com.citi.rb.gold.memfis.sb.war/src/main/webapp/citibank/eclipselite/bank/memfis/sb/maintenance/SBBondCalculatorPopup.jsp"
]
```

You can get the extensions like so:

```
strings.flat_map do |string|
  # in single line, regex is /(\.[^\.]+)$/
  # here is multiline form with explanation:
  regex = %r{
    (             # start of match group
      \.          # period
      [^\.]+ .    # any number of chars other than period
    )             # end of match group
    $             # end of string
  }x
  string.match(regex).captures
end
# => [".java", ".xml", ".jsp"]
```